# How can accomplish For-Each loop from the underscore template to mustache

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, mustache

I have an underscore template and I have to use [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io) to render it. Below is my underscore template:

```
<div id="sub-account">
    <p>something</p>
  <table>
    <tr><td>Name</td>

    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <% _.each(accountList, function(account) { %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= account.get('name') %></td>

            </tr>
        <% }) %>
    </tbody>
  </table>

 </div>
```

Im using a mustache as my main view to render a list. How can I loop through the code to render as a mustache template?

Backbone Collection:

```
var SubAccountCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(models, options) {
        this.account = options.id;
    },

    url: function() {
        return 'some/' +this.account + '/somelist';
    }
});

   return SubAccountCollection;
 });
```

This is what im trying to do with the ajax call:

```
accountList.fetch({

                success: function(accnlist){
                    setInterval(function(){
                        $('#sub-account-list').html(tmpl, {accnlist:accnlist.toJSON()})
                    }, 500);

                },
                error: function(err){
                    console.log('Error!', err)
                }
            });
```

Comment: Are you using Underscore templates or Mustache templates? If you're using Mustache then what does `_.templateSettings` matter?

Comment: well, right. I dont need it. but im not sure how to use a for-each loop using mustache given the function above in underscore

Comment: So you're trying to implement your Underscore template in Mustache, right? Is `accountList` an array of Backbone models perhaps? Mustache would really prefer that you hand it an array of simple objects.

Comment: can you show as an example that you're trying to suggest. Thanks

Comment: I still don't know what `accountList` is or where it comes from. Does it originate as a Backbone collection? If yes then maybe `toJSON` will help.

Comment: well, yes it comes from the backbone collection: var accountList = new SubAccountCollection();

Answer (score 1):

should be something like that. didn't check though.

```
<div id="sub-account">
    <p>something</p>
  <table>
    <tr><td>Name</td>

    </tr>
    <tbody>
        {{#accountList}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{name}}</td>

            </tr>
        {{/accountList}}
    </tbody>
  </table>

 </div>
```

Comment: there is something wrong with your list then, mustache is pretty simple in implementation, you can check an example for your case here: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#non-empty-lists